# cannot convert python bytes to Integer (invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\x16')

Tags: python-2.7

Am trying to decode ASN1 format data. As per the Data specification Document. Am expected to get 4 bytes and i need to convert the same to Integer.

```
    def decode_chargingId(self,field_length,field_value):
    print(field_lenght)
    return int(field_value)
```

Above is the piece of code being executed and i get below error for the same.

**invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\x16'**

When i try to see the bytes with break point in VS code debuggers i see the bytes as **b'\x16\x00\xf70'** .

Am just trying to get the integer value equivalent for those bytes using int function in python.

Answer (score 0):

I was sing wrong method to convert to integer. Below code worked fine to convert bytes to integer.

```
def decode_chargingId(self,field_length,field_value):
    result = 0
    for b in field_value:
        result = result * 256 + int(b)
    return result
```